# get the id of parent tr for a child td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the id of the parrent tr of the td:

In this  [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/8RF5r/7/)  I'm getting the id the td which has been chacked; I just return this value only if one row has been checked!

but

```
$(this).parent().attr("id")
```

gives me an undefined error! What is the correct way to get the id of parrent?

Thanks

Comment: please see http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/8RF5r/7/

Comment: sorry about that! but still "undefined"!

Comment: there are no id for the parent

Comment: Use `id = this.id`. `this` is already the `tr` element since you are iterating over them: `$("#my_tbl").find("tr")`. `$(this).parent()` would give you the (automatically created) `tbody` element which doesn't have an ID.

Comment: why am I getting minus score? :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
id = $(this).attr("id");
```

---

It's because you're looping through the `tr` of your table using `$("#my_tbl").find("tr").each(` so you're already at the `tr` level.

So there's no need to use `parent()` to traverse up to the parent anymore, you just need to use `$(this)` to target current row `tr` of checked `td` instead.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8RF5r/19/)**

Comment: @user3393991: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316123/get-the-id-of-parent-tr-for-a-child-td#comment33911214_22316123

Comment: But `id = this.id` is much more efficient and less to type. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$(this).parent().attr("id")` what you actualy get is `TBODY` element, try using `closest('table')` or `parents('table')` instead to find the parent `TABLE` of your `TR`.

From your example:

```
$("#my_tbl").find("tr").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("td:first").hasClass('checked'))
  {
    count = count + 1;
    id = ($(this).closest('table').attr('id'));
    // id = ($(this).parents('table').attr('id'));
  }
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8RF5r/20/)

Answer (score 0):

try with

just this works check demo

```
$(this).attr("id");
```

### `$(this)` here is referring to tr only

## [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/8RF5r/11/)

Comment: still undefined man! I did it in my jsfddle and it is still undefined!

Comment: Why should `.parent('tr')` work, which is even more restrictive than  `.parent()`? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @FelixKling you are right, firstly the tr was not having any id's, secondly, this was referring to tr only

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set this:

```
id = $(this).attr("id");
```

This is because you are working with currently with that tr.

Answer (score 0):

- use toggleClass() to switch the class
- use .map() to get the ids of checked tr elemets

Try

```
function myFunction(element) {
    $(element).find("td:first").toggleClass('checked');
}

function check() {
    var ids = $("#my_tbl tr td.checked").parent().map(function () {
        return this.id;
    }).get();

    if (ids.length > 0) {
        alert(ids.join());
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Rpgnd/)

---

A more jQueryish solution will be is to use jQuery event handlers like

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#my_tbl tr').click(function () {
        $(this).find("td:first").toggleClass('checked');
    })
    $('#check').click(function () {
        var ids = $("#my_tbl tr td.checked").parent().map(function () {
            return this.id;
        }).get();

        if (ids.length > 0) {
            alert(ids.join());
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6w4G5/)

If you want to support IE7+ only then [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6w4G5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check if parent tag/node has id attribute or not. Also, you would get a better answer if you could share what's your objective and relevant HTML